# Adding description to sharepoint link URL using the C# CSOM

Tags: development, client-object-model, sharepoint-online

I'm currently adding the URL except the description is an ugly link.
I would like to add the description to the URL in a `links` list on sharepoint online.

My current code to add a new item from an Azure Worker role is as follows :

```
        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(cmdSpoSite))
        {
            ctx.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(ctx_ExecutingWebRequest);

            if (ctx != null)
            {
                List oList = ... // List data etc

                oListItem["Title"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                oListItem["URL"] = url;
                // Adding the URL here but how do I change the description?

                oListItem.Update();

                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
```

The description as seen from the sharepoint list:

[image]

**Edit**

```
FieldUrlValue _url = new FieldUrlValue();
_url.Url = "http://www.google.com";
_url.Description = "Google";
oListItem["URL"] = _url;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SPFieldUrlValue url = new SPFieldUrlValue();
url.Url = "Your Url here";
url.Description = "Your description here";
oListItem["URL"] = url;
```

EDIT (for CSOM):

```
FieldUrlValue url = new FieldUrlValue();
url.Url = "Your Url here";
url.Description = "Your description here";
oListItem["URL"] = url;
```

Comment: Cheers, seems like this is in the `Microsoft.Sharepoint` assembly. Any way I could use `SPFieldUrlValue` in the sharepoint redistributeable. `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldurlvalue.aspx

Comment: Thanks mate, it wouldnt compile with `object does not contain a defintion ...` So i just instantiated a new `FieldUrlValue` as seen in my edit above; thank you kindly for your assistance.

Comment: Np dude. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a Microsoft.SharePoint.dll for O365 2013. Here is how I did it, cheers:

```
           ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            var lib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("All Project List");
            li = lib.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            li["Title"] = "New Item";
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue u = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUrlValue();
            u.Url = "http://www.espn.com";
            u.Description = "title";
            li["Project"] = u;
            li.Update();
            ctx.Load(li);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```