# How to read URL/Description from a Hyperlink field using CSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

Using CSOM (JavaScript) how do you get the URL and description fields from a Hyperlink field?

Comment: Did you check the SPFieldUrlValue class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee552494(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Yes - there's no complete example on there of how to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var myListItem = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ListName").getItemById(1);
context.load(myListItem);

context.executeQueryAsync(function(){

alert(myListItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_description());
alert(myListItem.get_item("HyperLinkFieldName").get_url());

},function(sender,args){alert(args.get_message());});
```

Comment: I did this and it worked fine. But it only gets a single record without using a CAML query. I tried to to add the the .get_url() and get_description() to my code that loops through all the items   
while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
markup += '<td>' + listItem.get_item('Name') + '</td>';
markup += '<td>' + listItem.get_item('Level') + '</td>';
markup += '<td> + listItem.get_item("URL").get_description() + '</td>';
markup +='</tr>'; 

This failed. If I remove the .get_description() it returns [object, Object]. Ideas why how to fit?